# How to update the packages in ipython like jupyter & spyder

Tags: python, pip, jupyter-notebook, ipython

I wrote this `!pip install seaborn` to install the updated version of seaborn, then the system shows a warning that [image]

then I wrote this `pip install --upgrade pip` trying to update the pip, it shows that [image]

Instead of running it in ipython, where should i run this code? How could I update package in ipython like jupyter?

Comment: you have to run it in terminal/console/cmd.exe - and it is main method to install or update modules

Comment: @furas how to run it in cmd.exe? I tried these command in cmd but it says unrecognized command

Comment: If  `pip` and `python` is in folder which is in variable PATH then system can easily find it. If system can't find it then you have to use full path to run it  `C:\full\path\to\pip install --update pip`. If you can run `python` without full path then you can use `python -m pip install --update pip`

Comment: @furas you are right, it works

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You just forgot put the `!` before `pip install --upgrade pip`.

Do this: `!pip install --upgrade pip`

See this for more information, if you are using conda:

https://jakevdp.github.io/blog/2017/12/05/installing-python-packages-from-jupyter/