# Heatmap doesnt display data properly

Tags: dataframe, seaborn, heatmap, correlation, figure

I usually plot a seaborn heatmap with any dataframe co-relation to find their relation however whenever I want to have yticklabels displayed. I get the  disrupted figure in the image at the following link (please clik the "enter image description here"). Can anyone tell me how to fix this thanks!!!!!
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3mJ07.png)

Comment: There was a problem with an old matplotlib version (3.1.1). Upgrading to the latest matplotlib and seaborn versions should solve the problem.

Comment: Hy @JohanC thank you for helping me out yes the link you suggested worked thank you but if you could tell me how can I install matplotlib (3.1.2)??? I am using jupyter notebook

Comment: See  [How to update the packages in ipython like jupyter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56226523/how-to-update-the-packages-in-ipython-like-jupyter-spyder).  Starting with an exclamation mark should do the trick `!pip install matplotlib --upgrade`

Comment: Okay Thank you!!!!